# Can subobjects be allocated separately from the rest of a derived class

Tags: java, inheritance, garbage-collection, jvm

Given this intentionally very simple pair of classes

```
class Base {
    private int a;
    private int b;
    public Base() {
        this.a = 0; 
        this.b = 0
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {
    private int c;
    Derived() {
        super();
        this.c = 0;
}
```

It is my understanding that doing `Derived d = new Derived();` will at least guarantee that `a` and `b` are allocated contiguously.  However, is it possible for the subobject `Base` to be separate from the remaining `c` in `Derived` in memory, or does the entire object have to be contiguously allocated.

Also, am I correct in my assumption that the two `int`s in `Base` would be contiguous?

Even if it is contiguously allocated, can the `Base` subobject separate from the rest of `Derived` upon leaving the Eden space?

Comment: It doesn't have to be allocated contiguously -- the JVM is free to allocate it any way it chooses so long as semantics are observed -- but most JVMs would do so, after any required padding.  There is no way (through the Java language) to control this behavior.

Comment: There is no guarantee that fields in an object (e.g. `a` and `b`) are allocated contiguously. The JVM could, for example, have some padding that it inherited from a superclass and might choose to backfill that padding with one of the fields. Alternatively, the JVM might profile your object and determine that `a` is rarely used while `b` is hot, and could choose to place `a` somewhere distant from the object. These are hypothetical - the JVM specification says nothing about how objects are laid out in memory.

Comment: (I worked on a JVM where the fields were "packed", with a shorter field (if there was one) occupying a vacant space in the header, and other fields rearranged so that proper type alignment occurred with minimal wasted space due to padding.  A char field of the derived class, eg, could end up tucked between two fields of the base class.)

Comment: Understand that, when you say `new Derived()`, the `new` operation (in any reasonably standard JVM) causes a single piece of storage large enough for the entire object to be allocated -- the spaces for Base and Derived are not separately allocated.

Comment: (In fact, the size of Derived may be the same as the size of Base, if there is at least 4 bytes of padding in Base.)

Answer (score 2):

> It is my understanig that doing Derived d = new Derived(); will at least guarantee that a and b are allocated contiguously.

This is incorrect. The JVM specification makes no such guarantee, and I am familiar with at least one major JVM implementation in which it is false.

> Also, am I correct in my assumption that the two ints in Base would be contiguous?

No. Again, the specification says nothing about how objects are laid out in memory.

> Even if it is contiguously allocated, can the Base subobject separate from the rest of Derived upon leaving the Eden space?

Yes it could. But since object layout isn't exposed in Java or JNI, this isn't relevant to most Java programmers.